# Insert a number into a position that already has a number to create a List

Tags: list, insert, numbers, lisp, common-lisp

I have this lisp code that is meant for a 4-in-a-row game

```
(defun board ()
'((
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
)
(NIL NIL)))
```

Each NIL represents a column (forget the last two NILs). In each column I can put up to game pieces, which can be 1 (represents white) or 10 (represents black). The following code is used to put game pieces in the place the player wants.

```
(defun get-level (level board)
 (cond ((= level 1) (first board))
  ((= level 2) (second board))
  ((= level 3) (third board))
  ((= level 4) (fourth board))
  ))

(defun get-column (column board)
 (cond ((= column 1) (first board))
  ((= column 2) (second board))
  ((= column 3) (third board))
  ((= column 4) (fourth board))
  ))

(defun get-line (line board)
 (cond ((= line 1) (first board))
  ((= line 2) (second board))
  ((= line 3) (third board))
  ((= line 4) (fourth board))
  ))

(defun get-elem (x y z board)
   (get-column y (get-line x (get-level z board))))

(defun value1 (x y z board)
   (insertValue x y z board '1))

(defun value10 (x y z board)
   (insertValue x y z board '10))

(defun insertValue (x y z board value)
 (cond ((= z 1)(list (act-levelValue x y (first board) value) (second board) (third board) (fourth board)))
 ((= z 2)(list (first board) (act-levelValue x y (second board) value) (third board) (fourth board)))
 ((= z 3)(list (first board) (second board) (act-nivelValor x y (third board) value) (fourth board)))
 ((= z 4)(list (first board) (second board) (third board) (act-levelValue x y (fourth board) value)))))

(defun act-levelValue (x y level value)
 (cond ((= x 1)(list (act-lineValue y (first level) valor) (second level) (third level) (fourth level)))
 ((= x 2)(list (first level) (act-lineValue y (second level) value) (third level) (fourth level)))
 ((= x 3)(list (first level) (second level) (act-lineValue y (third level) value) (fourth level)))
 ((= x 4)(list (first level) (second level) (third level) (act-linhaValor y (fourth level) value)))))

(defun act-lineValue (y line value)
  (cond ((= y 1) (list value (second line) (third line) (fourth line)))
  ((= y 2) (list (first line) value (third line) (fourth line)))
  ((= y 3) (list (first line) (second line) value (fourth line)))
  ((= y 4) (list (first line) (second line) (third line) value))))
```

When I try to insert a value on a empty position it works.

```
CL-USER 1 > (inserirValor 1 1 1 '(((NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL))(NIL NIL)) '10)
(((10 NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL)) (NIL NIL) NIL NIL)
```

But when I try to insert another value in the same position, it doesn't work. It just replaces the value that was previously there with the new one, when what I really wanted would be something like this:

```
CL-USER 1 > (inserirValor 1 1 1 '(((10 NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL))(NIL NIL)) '1)
((((1 10) NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL) (NIL NIL NIL NIL)) (NIL NIL) NIL NIL)
```

Can someone help me? What should I do? Create a new condition inside the `insertValue` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code duplication

You are not supposed to type so much. Think about [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) ;-)

Instead of `first`, `second`, etc. all over the place, you can use [`NTH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm) for simple access. 
And this works for different sizes, not just 4.

As for updating a board, you seem to have chosen to use nested lists and a purely functional approach (i.e. no mutation). You need to make a modified copy of a board. Let's define a helper function which replaces one element in a list in a purely functional way:

```
(defun replace-element (list n value)
  (nconc                  
   (subseq list 0 n)
   (list value)
   (subseq list (1+ n))))
```

<sub>(APPEND would work too in place of NCONC, but why allocate more memory?)</sub>

You can also copy and mutate:

```
(defun replace-element (list n value)
  (let ((copy
         (copy-list list)))
    (setf (nth N copy) value)
    copy))
```

Here is a test:

```
(let ((list '(a b c d e)))
  (loop
     for i below (length list)
     collect (replace-element list i '_)))

((_ B C D E)
 (A _ C D E)
 (A B _ D E)
 (A B C _ E)
 (A B C D _))
```

### Adding a value

You effectively add the value in the `act-lineValue` function. Instead of replacing the old value, think about how your data is initialized. You have NIL when the board is empty, which stands for empty lists.

That mean that you can put your value in front of the existing list instead of replacing the list that was already there.
Using the previous function, this becomes:

```
(replace-element line N (cons value (nth N line)))
```

### Other remarks

- Names in Lisp don't use CamelCase, but use the dash symbol for separating words. That means `level-value` instead of `levelValue`.
- Also, your names a little cryptic, I don't really know what the `act` prefix stands for. And `get-elem` should be `get-element`. Code is supposed to be readable.
- Why encode white and black with numbers? You are using Lisp, a language where you have symbolic values. Just use `'white` and `'black`, which incurs no efficiency penalty and is way more readable.

Comment: So what I should do is add your helper function into my program and in the insertValue function I should put `(replace-elt line N (cons value (nth N line)))` in what position? Where I have `(act-levelValue x y (first board) value)` ? Or a new condition in that function?

act = update, forgot to translate that.

Comment: First rewrite your get-xxx functions to use nth. Test. Try to rewrite acc-lineValue with my function. This should   be easy. Test. Then one level higher. Rewrite acc-levelValue. This is a little like the previous one, but you store the modified line. Test. Etc...